# Remotely copy files from network share to local drive path from a different remote machine

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to copy files from network share drive to the local drive path on a remote machine. The catch is the entire activity happens from another remote machine.

Server 1 (build server) - Has an orchestrator script which is trying to copy files from network drive of Server 2 to Server 2's local path.

Tried below -

```
Copy-Item "Z:\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\*" -Destination "\C:\sub-folder3\sub-folder2\sub-folder3" -Recurse -Force
```

This absolutely works fine if I run this directly in server 2 and fails with error Cannot find path 'Z:\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\' because it does not exist, if ran from server 1.

Hence tried adding server name with shared drive

```
Copy-Item "\\$servername\Z:\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\" -Destination "\C:\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\" -Recurse -Force
```

This does not return any error, but no file gets copied.

Am I doing anything wrong with my commands or its not the way to deal with network drives remotely.

Net use returns the below

[image]

Drive Properties 
[image]

Comment: i think you are seeing the "double hop problem". do a search here or on your fave search engine  for details & workaround methods. [*grin*]

Comment: It may be worth looking into `robocopy` if you're going to do this often.

Comment: How is the Z drive mounted? Is it a simple Windows mapped drive? Mapped drives only exist for the current logged in user....

Comment: `\\$servername\Z:` is not a valid file path, neither is `\C:`. You need to check when logged in to server2 to see the UNC path for mapping `Z:`, then use that. Format is `\\servername\sharename\subfolderpath`

Answer (score 1):

As @matthew stated in the comments, I recommend robocopy for copying between two remote machines.

```
robocopy \\servername1\z$\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\ \\servername2\c$\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\"
```

If for some reason you can't do robocopy, as @scepticalist and @Theo pointed out, doing `\\servername1\Z:` will not work. Typically, you'll use `Z$` in the path, although this can depend on your setup. Assuming that yours is set up this way, you would change your PowerShell command to be

```
Copy-Item "\\servername1\Z$\sub-folder1\sub-folder2\sub-folder3\" -Destination "\\Servername2\c$\sub-folder3\sub-folder2\sub-folder3" -Recurse -Force
```

As @Lee_Daily pointed out, you still may run into the "double hop" problem, in which case you will need to use Cred SSP authentication when performing the copies.

Comment: Effectively when working with UNC file paths and pointing to drive letters you'll always need to use `c$` when pointing towards the C drive.

Comment: Followed the same still no luck. as suggested by @Theo, i took the UNC path and used it as "\\servername\sharename\Z$\folder1\folder2" with Copy-item still it say Cannot find path because it does not exist. Also tried the same with robocoy, somehow the execution never ends. I waited for closely 2 minutes.

Comment: Depending on how large the copied files are, copying can take quite a while. I have robocopy scripts which run for hours on terabytes of data. The UNC path would not be `\\servername\sharename\z$\ ` . Make sure that you know what the actual path to the folders are. How do you navigate to them in file explorer? It will usually be `\\servername1\driveletter$\folder1`.

Comment: I'm currently working on the folder with just 4MB. I get a drive under network location in the explorer or in the address bar just typing Z: navigates to the drive.

Comment: That likely means that you have the `\\servername1\driveletter$\folder1` mapped to your Z drive. You need to figure out the full path.

Comment: @Nick i have updated the question with screenshots of the network drive. Thanks for your help

Comment: The part that you blacked out is the path you should be using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201271/discussion-between-ashwin-and-nick).